# limit Google maps of countries in the autocomplete list to “Australia”  but shows every one

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am using a Google API autocomplete. i try to restrict only for the Australia. But it suggests every cities in country.for example if i type "new" It suggests New York also. i don't want like that. I want to display only the cities in the Australia

The Working sample is in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NuCUd/8/).Thanks in advance

Comment: Must be a bug, you should report it.

Comment: Are you setting google.maps.places.ComponentRestrictions? May we see some code?

Comment: I have tried and tried with ComponentRestrictions, but I couldn't get it to work properly. It may indeed be a bug, as Dr.Molle suggested. You can report it here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/

Comment: As per Dr.Molle suggestion i reported as bug.

Comment: bug has been confirmed : http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4302&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

Comment: @Dr.Molle this issue has been fixed by google

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too late to answer perhaps...
But, this has worked for me:
Put the following in your `initialize()` method

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'au'}
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```