# Google Places Autocomplete API restrict country stopped working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete, restriction

I am running an google place auto complete item.

I placed a restriction to output only address on a particular country.  using the componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'} code.

This worked very fine, until 25 July 2012. The country restriction failed and all address are now suddenly displayed.

I have gone back to test the sample code on google map website 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete

and loaded it on 
http://jsfiddle.net/csdk3/

and I still get all address without restricted country.

Will appreciate if I could get some help.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [limit Google maps of countries in the autocomplete list to “Australia”  but shows every one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624521/limit-google-maps-of-countries-in-the-autocomplete-list-to-australia-but-show)

Comment: @user1550387 do you have similar problems to

Comment: if you mean me: no, I don't have problems, but I see that it's not working as expected and it's already confirmed as a bug by google, so the only thing you can do for now is: **wait for a bugfix**

Comment: thanks you. now I can go to sleep, realizing the fault is not from me.

Answer (score 1):

There was a [**bug**](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4302) which was recognized, and subsequently fixed by Google.

[**Demo**](http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_autocomplete.html) is working now. (Australian locations only)